# Tasks are no more supported on batch side since SonarQube 5.2

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I install SonarQube 5.2 and Sonar-runner 2.4 (latest versions). I managed to start SonarQube but I get the following error when trying to run Sonar-runner:

```
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Tasks are no more supported on batch side since SonarQube 5.2
ERROR:
```

EDIT:
The following exception is thrown when I run the command with --debug

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: Tasks are no more supported on batch side since SonarQube 5.2
```

It is there any configuration that should be changed to be able to analyze a project?

Thank you

Comment: What command are you trying to run?

Comment: /opt/sonar-runner/sonar-runner /home/build/project, where /opt/sonar-runner is the directory where sonar-runner is installed and /home/build/project is the directory of a Java project, with a sonar-project.properties file inside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must execute sonar-runner *from* the project base directory. So

```
cd my/project/base/dir
sonar-runner
```

**EDIT**

The base assumption with `sonar-runner` is that you're invoking it *in* the directory where you want it to do its work. The only arguments* it ever took were "tasks" to be performed, but those are no longer supported.

*Note that you *can* define (-D) parameters to be used during analysis on the command line.

Comment: It seems that using this way the runner is working as expected. Any reason for this behavior?

Comment: @nucandrei I've expanded my answer to (hopefully) address your comment

Comment: That makes sense. The only problem is that this "feature" is not documented or I could not find any reference to it. Thank you.

Comment: Says pretty clearly to "Run the following command from the project base directory" http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner

Comment: I was referring to not running from another directory. But everything is clear now.