# Sonar runner execution fails with Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am using Sonar Runner with maven project.
when I run this using cmd as "sonar-runner",things are working fine.

However when I do the same using Jenkins "Post Step" function,I get the below error.
Please advise.

```
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\software\sonar-runner-dist-2.4\sonar-runner-2.4\DFServer\pom.xml to DFTK/DFTK/8/DFTK-8.pom
channel stopped
[workspace] $ D:\software\sonar-runner-dist-2.4\sonar-runner-2.4\bin\sonar-runner.bat DFServer -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/ ******** ******** -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=C:\Users\ravi13341\.jenkins\jobs\DFServer\workspace -Dproject.settings=D:\software\sonar-runner-dist-2.4\sonar-runner-2.4\DFServer\sonar-project.properties -Dsonar.language=java -Dsonar.projectName=D:\sonar_test\DFServer -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 -Dsonar.binaries=D:\software\sonarqube-5.2\lib -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.projectKey=org.sonarqube:java-sonar-runner-simple -Dsonar.sources=D:\software\sonar-runner-dist-2.4\sonar-runner-2.4\DFServer\src
D:\software\sonar-runner-dist-2.4\sonar-runner-2.4
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.7.0_02 Oracle Corporation (32-bit)
Windows 7 6.1 x86
INFO: Runner configuration file: D:\software\sonar-runner-dist-2.4\sonar-runner-2.4\conf\sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: D:\software\sonar-runner-dist-2.4\sonar-runner-2.4\DFServer\sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.2
15:14:36.803 INFO  - Load global repositories
15:14:36.927 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=109ms
15:14:36.943 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\ravi13341\.sonar\cache
15:14:37.255 INFO  - Load plugins index
15:14:37.271 INFO  - Load plugins index (done) | time=16ms
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.144s
Final Memory: 3M/71M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Tasks are no more supported on batch side since SonarQube 5.2
ERROR: 
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Build step 'Invoke Standalone Sonar Analysis' marked build as failure
Skipping sonar analysis due to bad build status FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Console screenshot:

[[image: Console screenshot]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should omit the `DFServer` attribute to the sonar-runner call.

See also this explanation on SO here: [Tasks are no more supported on batch side since SonarQube 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528873/tasks-are-no-more-supported-on-batch-side-since-sonarqube-5-2)

Comment: Thanks. It worked.
In the configuration, I had given the name of the task and Jenkins was appending that task name after the sonar-runner.bat in command line.

Thanks for your answer.It worked.