# execute sonarqube scanner jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

*I want to execute a "SonarQube Scanner" for jenkins*

But now
           This is the configuration file:
After execution, an error is displayed

```
  **-Dsonar.projectKey=Hotel \
  -Dsonar.host.url=http://23.101.**** \
  -Dsonar.login=4df48c69cc5a8783a5443a5af84824******
sonar.login=admin
 sonar.password=******
sonar.verbose=true
sonar.language=java 
sonar.sources=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/$JOB_NAME/
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.exclusions= src
sonar.projectVersion=1.0**
```

```
Running as SYSTEM
    Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Hotel_API
    using credential 27c26c58-35d2-46dc-8872-606bae698be6
      git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
    Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
      git config remote.origin.url https://gitlab.com/tunv15/hotel-api.git # timeout=10
    Fetching upstream changes from https://gitlab.com/tunv15/hotel-api.git
      git --version # timeout=10
    using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
      git fetch --tags --progress https://gitlab.com/tunv15/hotel-api.git
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
      git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
      git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
    Checking out Revision 4460a9b58f517d823e8773df51a0564bb2fe6673 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
      git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
      git checkout -f 4460a9b58f517d823e8773df51a0564bb2fe6673
    Commit message: "Update HOTEL-API_sonar-project.properties"
      git rev-list --no-walk 4460a9b58f517d823e8773df51a0564bb2fe6673 # timeout=10
    Injecting SonarQube environment variables using the configuration: Hotel_API
    [Hotel_API] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/Hotel_API/bin/sonar-scanner Sonar -D-X -Dsonar.host.url=http://23.101.****
-Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.sources=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Hotel_API/ -Dsonar.language=java -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.exclusions=src/** "-D-Dsonar.projectKey=Hotel -Dsonar.host.url=http://23.10***
-Dsonar.login=4df48c69cc5a8783a5443a5af84*****" -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 -Dsonar.verbose=true -Dsonar.password=**** -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Hotel_API
    INFO: Scanner configuration file: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/Hotel_API/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
    INFO: Project root configuration file: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Hotel_API/sonar-project.properties
    04:08:56.184 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 4.0.0.1744
    04:08:56.186 INFO: Java 9.0.4 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
    04:08:56.186 INFO: Linux 4.15.0-1055-azure amd64
    04:08:56.369 DEBUG: keyStore is : 
    04:08:56.369 DEBUG: keyStore type is : pkcs12
    04:08:56.369 DEBUG: keyStore provider is : 
    04:08:56.369 DEBUG: init keystore
    04:08:56.370 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
    04:08:56.507 DEBUG: Create: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
    04:08:56.507 INFO: User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
    04:08:56.508 DEBUG: Create: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache/_tmp
    04:08:56.510 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
    04:08:56.513 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
    04:08:56.513 DEBUG: Download: http://23.101.9.197/batch/index
    04:08:56.565 DEBUG: Get bootstrap completed
    04:08:56.570 DEBUG: Create isolated classloader...
    04:08:56.604 DEBUG: Start temp cleaning...
    04:08:56.610 DEBUG: Temp cleaning done
    04:08:56.610 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
    04:08:56.621 INFO: SonarQube server 7.9.1
    04:08:56.622 DEBUG: Execution execute
    04:08:56.877 WARN: SonarScanner will require Java 11+ to run starting in SonarQube 8.x
    04:08:56.879 DEBUG: Community 7.9.1.27448
    04:08:56.976 INFO: Load global settings
    04:08:57.622 DEBUG: GET 200 http://23.101.9.197/api/settings/values.protobuf | time=645ms
    04:08:57.652 INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=676ms
    04:08:57.655 INFO: Server id: 32FADB56-AWviJsnh2_A_tHfY_aqj
    04:08:57.685 INFO: User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
    04:08:57.692 INFO: Load/download plugins
    04:08:57.694 INFO: Load plugins index
    04:08:58.304 DEBUG: GET 200 http://23.101.9.197/api/plugins/installed | time=609ms
    04:08:58.347 INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=653ms
    04:08:58.400 INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=708ms
    04:08:58.460 DEBUG: Plugins:
    04:08:58.460 DEBUG:   * SonarPython 1.14.0.3086 (python)
    04:08:58.460 DEBUG:   * SonarCSS 1.1.1.1010 (cssfamily)
    04:08:58.460 DEBUG:   * GitHub Authentication for SonarQube 1.5.0.870 (authgithub)
    04:08:58.460 DEBUG:   * JaCoCo 1.0.2.475 (jacoco)
    04:08:58.460 DEBUG:   * SonarGo 1.1.1.2000 (go)
    04:08:58.460 DEBUG:   * SonarKotlin 1.5.0.315 (kotlin)
    04:08:58.460 DEBUG:   * Svn 1.9.0.1295 (scmsvn)
    04:08:58.461 DEBUG:   * SonarJS 5.2.1.7778 (javascript)
    04:08:58.461 DEBUG:   * SonarRuby 1.5.0.315 (ruby)
    04:08:58.461 DEBUG:   * SonarScala 1.5.0.315 (sonarscala)
    04:08:58.461 DEBUG:   * SonarC# 7.15.0.8572 (csharp)
    04:08:58.461 DEBUG:   * SonarJava 5.13.1.18282 (java)
    04:08:58.461 DEBUG:   * LDAP 2.2.0.608 (ldap)
    04:08:58.462 DEBUG:   * SonarHTML 3.1.0.1615 (web)
    04:08:58.462 DEBUG:   * Git 1.8.0.1574 (scmgit)
    04:08:58.462 DEBUG:   * SonarFlex 2.5.1.1831 (flex)
    04:08:58.462 DEBUG:   * SonarXML 2.0.1.2020 (xml)
    04:08:58.462 DEBUG:   * SAML 2.0 Authentication for SonarQube 1.1.0.181 (authsaml)
    04:08:58.462 DEBUG:   * SonarPHP 3.2.0.4868 (php)
    04:08:58.462 DEBUG:   * SonarTS 1.9.0.3766 (typescript)
    04:08:58.462 DEBUG:   * SonarVB 7.15.0.8572 (vbnet)
    04:08:58.488 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    04:08:58.488 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
    04:08:58.488 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    04:08:58.488 INFO: Total time: 2.372s
    04:08:58.519 INFO: Final Memory: 6M/21M
    04:08:58.519 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    04:08:58.519 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
    04:08:58.519 ERROR: Tasks support was removed in SonarQube 7.6.
    04:08:58.519 ERROR: 
    04:08:58.519 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeeded?
    WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeeded?
    ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 2
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528873/tasks-are-no-more-supported-on-batch-side-since-sonarqube-5-2

Comment: Please help me , Issue not fix

Answer (score 0):

Your command starts with `sonar-scanner Sonar`. Remove the word `Sonar` from the list of arguments.

All arguments should start with a `-`. Please check the documentation for the tool and arguments here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/